# How can I set image for image control in windows store app?

Tags: image, file, windows-store-apps

How can I set image for image control in windows store app?
Like:

```
pic.source = new Bitmap.FromFile(@"D:\a.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

The image source can be set from XAML code 
`<image Source="/Assets/image.jpg"`

or using a BitmapImage and setting its UriSource

ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source

Comment: thank you!but this code not work `BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"E:\nicol - Copy.png");

            pic1.Source = bitmapImage;` Where am I wrong?

Comment: `<image Source="/Assets/image.jpg"` set project file. i want set other file